# How do I write that I have received a grant and that the work I am currently doing is being supported by that said grant?

Tags: phrases, expressions

I am writing to an educational institute that I am doing work/study with the grant that I have received from a specific foundation. Do I say, I am working alongside the grant? I am working through the grant? I am doing work using the grant?

Comment: "I am working with the support of a grant from the XYZ Foundation" is probably how I would put it.

Answer (score 1):

***I am working on the ABC project, with the support of a grant from the XYZ Foundation*** is probably how I would put it.

Answer (score 0):

Or more succinctly, ”I am completing my Doctoral research under a Pritzker Foundation grant”. .” If you don’t want or need to identify the foundation just say, “I will be continuing my studies at U of C, under a prior grant”.

Comment: If I read this I might think the Pritzker Foundation Grant is the sort of thing you'd be given before starting your Doctorate, that would continue until you graduate. As opposed to say a fixed-term grant and researcher could apply for.